# python reassigment of variable

Tags: python, scoping

I'm new to python (using 2.7.6) and I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find an answer anywhere.  I've looked at the python scoping rules and I don't understand what is happening in the following code (which converts three hex number strings to integers)

```
ls=['a','b','c']
d=ls
for i in range(0,len(d)):
    d[i]=int(d[i],64)

print str(ls)
```

Why does the value of ls change along with the value of d?

I couldn't repeat this behavior with simple assignments.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d` **is** `ls`.

**Not** the value assigned to `d` equals the value assigned to `ls`.  The two are one and the same.  This is typical Python behavior, not just for lists.

A simple way to do what you want is

```
d = ls[:]
```

Comment: this link that was provided in the duplicate question was what I was looking for: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables

Comment: For anyone else confused by this I suggest reading all of the comments in the duplicate question.  Very helpful...